# Capturing FTP File permissions details using Java FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, client

I'm trying to print the permission like this ( drwxrwxr-x ) of given file using the FTPClient with Java

but i couldn't find a way for that

i have tried many ways by sending commands to FTP

```
System.out.println(client.doCommandAsStrings("ls", "-l")[0]);
```

and

```
client.sendCommand("ls -l");
System.out.println(client.getReplyString());
```

is there a way for that ?